# Rails - Route to a different controller based on an object's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I currently have this url

```
devices/1/subdevices/9/simulator
```

Which is routed in the following way

```
resources :devices do
  resources :subdevices do
    resource :simulator, only: [:show] do
      post :open, :on => :member
      post :close, :on => :member
      post :start_motion, :on => :member
      post :stop_motion, :on => :member
    end
  end
end
```

This currently goes straight to simulator_controller.rb

I want to be able keep this url, but use separate simulator controllers depending on the type of subdevice.

So if the subdevice type is a motion device - route to simulators/motion_controller.rb, and if the subdevice type is an etrv - route to simulators/etrv_controller.rb etc

Any idea if this is possible?

Thanks.